# Xamarin Forms: The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm facing an SSL connection issue on Xamarin Forms. It was working fine initially but now it is giving the exception. The same API is working fine in another project.

```
    var siteIdResponse = await client.GetAsync(API CALL);
```

My **Xamarin.Forms** version is **4.5.0282**.

My project type is Portable type.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
> at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132

For reference, I have created a sample project and uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gBKs08s3hdth_rIbcBqsuCWF6q_BqmY0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" - have you tested your server's certificate to see if it is valid?

Comment: @Jason The same API call is working on another project(.net), only on this project(portable), we are facing this issue.

Comment: it is working on a completely different platform that may enforce different restrictions on HTTPS connections.  You still need to check your server's certificate.

Comment: @Jason I have created a sample project and added its details on the question could you please have a look?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6351#issuecomment-932944425

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/21233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a dependenceService to Get HttpClientHandler.

Firstly. Create a interface.

```
public interface IMyOwnNetService
{
    HttpClientHandler GetHttpClientHandler();
}
```

Then achieve this interface in android.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyOwnNetService))]
namespace Business_App.Droid
{
    internal class MyOwnNetService : IMyOwnNetService
    {
        public HttpClientHandler GetHttpClientHandler()
        {
            return new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

iOS

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyOwnNetService))]
public class MyOwnNetService: IMyOwnNetService {
    public HttpClientHandler GetHttpClientHandler() {
        return new HttpClientHandler();
    }
}
```

In the end, use HttpClient like following code.

```
var hc = new HttpClient(Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IMyOwnNetService>().GetHttpClientHandler());
var siteIdResponse = await hc.GetAsync(API CALL);
```